# Strange sequence and limsup, liminf and limit points

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let $a_{n}$ be defined recursively as follows:

$a_{n} = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox {if } n = 1 \\ 1 &\mbox{if } n = 2 \\ \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-2} - a_{n-1}) &\mbox{if } a_{n-1} = 0 \\ 1 - \frac{1}{2}(a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) &\mbox{if } a_{n-1} = 1 \\ 2a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} &\mbox{otherwise }  \end{cases} $

Show that the set of limit points of $a_{n}$ is the interval $[0,1]$. Deduce that $\limsup a_{n} = 1$

---

I tried to first compute some terms of the sequence to see the overall behavior. I had that $a_{1} = 0, a_{2} = 1, a_{3} = \frac{1}{2}, a_{4} = 0,  a_{5} = \frac{1}{4},  a_{6} = \frac{1}{2},  a_{7} = \frac{3}{4},  a_{8} = 1$, so apparently the sequence has periodic behavior on the interval $[0, 1]$. As well, between each successive terms, it seems that $\lim (a_{n} - a_{n-1}) = 0$ (as their differences will be $\frac{1}{2^{k}}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, with $k$ ultimately increasing).

However, I'm completely lost on how to prove that for every $x \in [0,1]$, there exists a subsequence $a_{n_{k}}$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} a_{n_{k}}= x$. Or is there a better way of defining this sequence such that the proof of this fact is easier? If this is true, then the other part of the problem, $\limsup a_{n} = 1$, follows immediately due to the fact that $\sup[0,1] = 1$ (as it will be the supremum of the set of limit points which is $[0,1]$).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It does, for $a_{3}$ we have $a_{2} = 1$, so we have $a_{3} = \frac{1}{2}$, Then, for a_{4} we get into the case $2a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$, and as $a_{3} = \frac{1}{2}$ and $a_{2} = 1$, we will have $a_{4} = 1 - 1 = 0$ and so forth (note that for $a_{5}$, $a_{4} = 0$).